# Proper method of sending haproxy logs on alpine linux container to stdout

Tags: docker, logging, openshift, haproxy, alpine-linux

I have build a nice clean small haproxy alpine linux container.  This works great but there some problems I need to debug.  I have done a lot of research on how to do this properly but the examples are for ubuntu.

With Alpine being so thin it seams to be a hard to find the proper way to forward or have logs be displayed in the stdout so we can see the logs in Kubernetes or Openshift logs.

Any help on this topic would be great.

Comment: What paths have you tried to set the error log to? Does ``/dev/fd/1`` exist inside the container and have you tried that? Does ``/proc/1/fd/1`` exist or is there no proc filesystem?